# A margin in the page hiding the navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have this navbar and one hero section, and when scrolling a little bit the navbar is hidden. I am using React styled components.

[image]

I have already set these css:

```
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Play", sans-serif;
    }
```

This is the navbar CSS:

```
      background: #000;
      height: 80px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1rem;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 0;
    
      @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        transition: 0.8s all ease;
      }
```

Comment: Can you please check the syntax of the navbar CSS? Seems you have made a copy paste mistake while writing your question.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide enough information for us to understand the problem. Also take the [tour].